# Concatenating multiple .txt in files in subdirectories

Tags: python, file, windows-7, cat

I have multiple .txt files in different levels of subdirectory. All txt files are in the final iteration, that is, there is no level with both .txt files and further directories. I want to concatenate them all into one new text file, but can't find a simple way to go through all the subdirectories.

A command I've found, that is to be entered into the python command line terminal thus:

```
$ cat source/file/*.txt > source/output/output.txt
```

But I am not sure how I could make this iterate over multiple subdirectories.
(I am a real beginner with python, there seems to be some confusion. Is this not a python command? The source I found it from claimed it was...)

Comment: I fail to see how Python is related to this?

Comment: `cat` isn't a windows utility.

Comment: If you're talking about Cygwin in Windows 7, `find /source/dir -name *.txt -exec cat {} >> /destination/dir/output.txt \;` should work.

Comment: i would prefer `find source_dir -name "*.txt" -type f | xargs cat > output.file.txt` (does not start a new cat on every file)

Comment: @Henry please make it clear, if you are looking for cygwin solution, or pure windows command line (where there is no `cat`).

Comment: If you wanted a python solution `import fileinput;with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:out.writelines(fileinput.input())`.

Comment: `cat` is the least important problem here, as `type` does (almost?) the same thing on Win.

Comment: I apologise if there is a misunderstanding, I am only a beginner with python. I thought that the python command line could take cat, I understand from the responses that this is not a python command at all?
This was initially written as a question about python, someone edited it to take out all python references, which seems to be the source of some of the confusion...

Answer (score 0):

You could build them using a python script using something like:

```
file_list = ['c:\data.txt', 'c:\folder1\data.txt']

for everything in file_list:
    f = open(everything)
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line
```

Call the script from cmd e.g. \python.exe 'buildtxtfiles.py'

Comment: Would the file_list only have to include the top folder, or would I have to list all directories and subdirectories? There are thousands of subdirectories, I am looking for a solution that can go through them for me, rather than having to define a list in advance...